# Can I farm XP/resources on a VIP extraction mission?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I've just been tasked to recover a VIP from a hostile area by the council.  After the VIP has been found, I have to get her to the extraction zone.  During this time, aliens spawn randomly on the map.

Right now I way outclass the aliens that are appearing - they're Thin Men and I can typically one-shot them.  Additionally, if I leave my team in overwatch, the aliens typically drop into areas with no cover and stay there through my turn.  Suffice it to say they're sitting ducks.

It occurs to me that I could just farm these guys - both for XP and for weapon fragments.    Is this actually possible?  Will I continue to get credit for kills while I'm in the progress of extracting the VIP?  Is there some failure condition I will eventually run into?  Or do the aliens eventually start to get harder, which would limit my gains?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The aliens in extraction missions spawn neither indefinitely nor randomly. Spawning of each one is triggered when the VIP reaches a map area.

After you extracted the VIP, you still need to take out the remaining aliens. So you have to kill them all anyway.

Comment: Aww, drat. Good idea though, agent86. :)

Comment: that explains why sometimes I end the mission with no additional spawns :P

Comment: *"After you extracted the VIP, you still need to take out the remaining aliens"* - I've seen the mission end once VIP reaches the extraction zone. It is possible however, that I already did kill all the aliens.

Comment: I had this happen to me in the mission where you extract the general on the broken bridge. I ignored the two thin men on the plateau on the far side of the level and escorted the VIP out. When the VIP reached the extraction zone, I got a voice message from Bradford which was something like "Good work, now take out the remaining aliens" and a new mission objective. I had to return to the bridge and snipe the two thin men. Then the mission endend.

Comment: Yeah, I tested this on the next VIP mission after I read this answer.  I'd never noticed the correlation between the aliens dropping and the VIP moving closer to the extraction zone.  I also left a couple of aliens alone (they dropped in on the other side of the map from me) and I was told to go kill them before the mission would end.